# AudioManager volume starts high then goes low

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-audiomanager

I have the following code to play the default ringtone when a call is incoming.
Here is the code:

```
public AudioPlayer(Context c){
    AudioManager am = (AudioManager)c.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_RINGTONE);
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
}

public void playRingtone(){
    try{
        mp.setDataSource(mContext.getApplicationContext(), Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI);
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("AudioManager: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}

public void stopRingtone(){
    if(mp.isPlaying()){
        mp.stop();
        mp.reset();
        mp.release();
    }
}
```

This code starts playing the ringtone at the proper volume level but then cuts out and plays really really low. What is the reason for the change in volume and how can I fix it?

Thank you for your help